# Download Progress Status, when file is downloading from Google Drive?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, download

I am able to download files from Google drive, but I want to know the download progress. Can any one tell me how to do it?

I have tried this for downloading the files:

```
NSString *downloadURL = [[self.driveFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] downloadUrl];
GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [self.driveService.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:downloadURL];
filename=[[NSString alloc] init];
[fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     GTLDriveFile *file = [driveFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n");
     NSLog(@"This is File Size=====>%@",file.fileSize);
     NSLog(@"This is file Name===>%@",file.title);

     if(file.downloadUrl!= nil)
     {
         if (data!=nil)
         {
             filename=file.title;

             NSArray *paths =    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
             NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
             documentsDirectory = [[paths   objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",filename]];
             [data writeToFile:documentsDirectory atomically:YES];
```

Comment: It's very hard to answer a question like this without providing anymore information. You could provide the code you use, and maybe a link to the API etc.

Comment: @NSAddict plz check the update code for downloading file from google drive.. how can i know download progress when file is downloading....

Comment: Added my answer, hope it helps

Comment: @NSAddict i will implement and let u know... Thanks

Comment: @NSAddict i have declared long int for totalnumber of bytes globally ..but i m not getting the progress.. can u clear my doubt...

Comment: @NSAddict i implemented ur suggested code.... but can u tell me where can i call this method or it will automatically called..when file start downloading..can u clear my doubt

Comment: @NSAddict it will be appreciable..if u clear my doubt...thanks

Comment: Does the `myFetcher:receivedData:` method get called at all?

Comment: You have to add your instance as a delegate, so call `[fetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(completionMethod)];`, now copy the code you had in the completion block into a method called `completionMethod`. The `myFetcher:receivedData:` method should now get called automatically

Comment: You have my support email, what's the problem? Delete your comments, they don't belong here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit

---

I found a much simpler solution. There is a block that will be used for callbacks of the progress:

```
GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher =
    [self.driveService.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:downloadURL];
GTLDriveFile *file = [driveFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[fetcher setReceivedDataBlock:^(NSData *data) {
    NSLog(@"%f%% Downloaded", (100.0 / [file.fileSize longLongValue] * [data length]));
}];
```

Comment: but `file.fileSize` doesn't come every time. Sometime it is `null`.